# Image source URL rewriting without getting image from those URL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two sites as follows:

```
http://www.site1.com
http://www.site2.com
```

Images are coming from the first site to second site like `http://www.site1.com/images/logo.png` and I want to show the URL in second site like `http://wwww.site2.com/images/logo.png` using `htaccess`

Please help me how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried something? Add your code you tried, and the errors /logs if you have , in this way, will be more easy to help you

Comment: Right now I am testing it on localhost. Images are coming from first site and I want to show the URL of second site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your Root/.htaccess file on domain1

```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/images/(.*)$ http://www.jbtravels.com/images/$1
```